# Pass extra arguments to nested Serializer in Django Rest Framework

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I have such serializer:

```
 class FirstModelSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

       secondModel = SecondModelSerializer()

       class Meta:
            model = FirstModel
            fields = '__all__'
```

Where secondModel is ManyToMany field of FirstModel.

Is there any way to pass FirstModel object id to SecondModelSerializer?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

It was easier then I thought. I just had to use context like this

```
class FirstModelSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

      secondModel = SerializerMethodField()

      class Meta:
            model = FirstModel
            fields = '__all__'

      def get_secondModel(self, obj):
          return SecondModelSerializer(obj.secondModel.all(), many=True, context={'first_model_id': obj.id)).data
```

And use self.context.get('first_model_id') in SecondModelSerializer to get to this id.